# Spring MVC Form Not Submitting Value

Tags: java, forms, spring-mvc, modelattribute

### Resolution

I've now managed to get this working.

It was my own oversight that was causing the null result, and thanks to @WillKeeling for pointing out that I was mapping the form to the wrong controller method.

Rather than creating a new Role object for the form to submit, I was (for an unknown reason) asking it to submit a User object.

My working JSP & Controller below:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/users/${user.username}/addRole" modelAttribute="newRole">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Roles</span>
        <form:select class="form-control" path="rolename" multiple="false">
            <form:options items="${roles}" title="rolename" itemValue="rolename" itemLabel="rolename" />
        </form:select>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><input type="submit" value="Add Role" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning"/></span>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

**Controller Mapping**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{username}/addRole", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addUserRoles(@ModelAttribute("newRole") Role  newRole, @PathVariable("username") String username) {
    System.out.println(newRole.getRolename());
    return "redirect:/users/" + username;
}
```

### Original Question

I may be missing something obvious here but I was hoping someone may be able to help.

I'm building an access management system for the team I work in. I've got a form on a jsp (code below) which should submit a new "role" object that can be handled into the repository in the back end.

At the moment however, when I click submit the logging reports that the value is "null". Can somebody please shed some light on why this is?

#### Form in JSP

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/users/${user.username}/addRole" modelAttribute="user">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Roles</span>
        <form:select class="form-control" path="roles" multiple="false">
            <form:options items="${roles}" title="roles" itemValue="rolename" itemLabel="rolename" />
        </form:select>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><input type="submit" value="Add Role" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning"/></span>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

#### Controller

Original path is /users with the following controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{username}/addRole", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addUserRoles(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
    System.out.println(user.getRoles());
    return "redirect:/users/" + user.getUsername();
}
```

#### Result in Console

```
Role [rolename=null]
```

Comment: You will probably need to add custom converter for your Role object.

Comment: Have a look at WebDataBinder and PropertyEditorSupport.

Comment: You sure the form is posting to that particular controller method? The form's action is `/users/${user.username}/roles` but the controller method  is mapped to `/{username}/addRole`

Comment: @WillKeeling Sorry about that, I'll update my post. I've mapped it to the correct controller method now. Issue still remains.